# Запрос на блокированный сайт с локального сервера

Tags: сервер, http, доступ, denwer

Хочу сделать HTTP запрос; работаю через Денвер. Но оказалось, что нужный адрес заблокирован интернет-провайдером.

Можно ли как-нибудь продолжить работу, оставаясь на локальном сервере?

Comment: Если провайдер не пускает вас на ресурс, HTTP-запрос от сервера с локальной машины тоже не пройдет. Придется либо проксировать запрос, либо выполнять его с сервера в сети, где доступ к нужному вам ресурсу не ограничен.

Comment: Работать через прокси, тоже не получилось ведь прокси тупо сбивает локальную машину